# How can I clean pacman's database of missing files?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman

I was experimenting with some new desktop managers and I ended up screwing up my machine. At this point, I'd like to get rid of lightdm and start over, but I can't seem to remove it.

`pacman -Ssq lightdm` yields:

```
liblightdm-qt4
liblightdm-qt5
lightdm
lightdm-gtk-greeter
lightdm-kde-greeter
deepin-session-ui
light-locker
lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings
lightdm-ubuntu
lightdm-unity-greeter
lightdm-remote-session-freerdp
lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure
```

`pacman -Qo lightdm-gtk-greeter` yields:

```
error: failed to find 'lightdm-gtk-greeter' in PATH: NO such file or directory
```

What is up with that? Does this mean what I think it means? There are things in the pacman database that don't exist on the filesystem anymore? How can I clean this up?

Comment: What does `pacman -Ql lightdm-gtk-greeter` show?

Comment: @jasonwryan `error: package 'ligthdm-gtk-greeter' was not found`

Comment: So, it is either not installed, or is installed but not in pacman's database (I would suspect the former)...

Comment: Tell me something I don't know ;)

Comment: You used the wrong flags: you don't have it installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Ssq` flag queries the sync database. Unless you have installed all the packaged in the repos, there should be things in the sync database that are not installed on your machine. To find packages that are installed locally, you need to query the local database with `-Qsq`.